# Rails- something stops working when validator uncommented

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

When I uncomment line 'validates_presence_of :username', error 'can't convert String into Integer' happens when I open view seen below.

Restarting server doesn't help.

Model:

```
require 'digest/sha1'
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
#validates_uniqueness_of :username
  validates_presence_of :username
  #has_many :votes
  #has_many :sentences, :through => :votes

  def self.make_salt(username="")
    Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(username+"#{Time.now}#{Kernel.rand}")
  end

  def self.hash(password="")
    Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(password)
  end
end
```

View:

```
<h2>Users</h2>
<table class="listing" summary="Users list">
  <tr class="header">
    <th>Username</th>
    <th>Actions</th>
  </tr>
  <% @users.each do |user| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= user.username %></td>
    <td>
      <%= link_to('Show',{:action => 'show',:id => user.id}) %>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

Application trace is blank.

Framework trace:

```
activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/descendants_tracker.rb:23:in `delete'
activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/descendants_tracker.rb:23:in `clear'
activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/descendants_tracker.rb:21:in `each'
activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/descendants_tracker.rb:21:in `clear'
railties (3.0.7) lib/rails/application/bootstrap.rb:59:in `_callback_after_1'
activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:421:in `_run_call_callbacks'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:44:in `call'
rack (1.2.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:107:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:48:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:47:in `call'
railties (3.0.7) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:13:in `call'
rack (1.2.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.2.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `call'
rack (1.2.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `synchronize'
rack (1.2.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:30:in `call'
railties (3.0.7) lib/rails/application.rb:168:in `call'
railties (3.0.7) lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `send'
railties (3.0.7) lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
railties (3.0.7) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.2.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:13:in `call'
rack (1.2.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:52:in `service'
/usr/lib64/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:104:in `service'
/usr/lib64/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:65:in `run'
/usr/lib64/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:173:in `start_thread'
/usr/lib64/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start'
/usr/lib64/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start_thread'
/usr/lib64/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:95:in `start'
/usr/lib64/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `each'
/usr/lib64/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `start'
/usr/lib64/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:23:in `start'
/usr/lib64/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:82:in `start'
rack (1.2.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:13:in `run'
rack (1.2.2) lib/rack/server.rb:213:in `start'
railties (3.0.7) lib/rails/commands/server.rb:65:in `start'
railties (3.0.7) lib/rails/commands.rb:30
railties (3.0.7) lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `tap'
railties (3.0.7) lib/rails/commands.rb:27
script/rails:6:in `require'
script/rails:6
```

Scheme.rb: ( part with users table )

```
create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "username"
  t.string   "e-mail"
  t.string   "hashed_password"
  t.string   "salt"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end

add_index "users", ["username"], :name => "index_users_on_username"
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: Can you post the backtrace from the error?

Comment: Could you post the schema.rb file?

Comment: @mosch I have posted part with users table

Comment: Do you talk about validates_presence_of or validates_uniqueness_of because you said : "When I uncomment line 'validates_presence_of :username'" you get error but validates_uniqueness_of is not commented ?

Comment: @Dinatih Actually, I tried both, and neither of them works. In original, when it works, all of them are commented.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your migration:
add_index "users", ["username"], :name => "index_users_on_username", unique => true

Maybe he can solve it and it's better if you really want to validate uniqueness of username in DB too

Comment: add_index "users", ["username"], :name => "index_users_on_username", :unique => true            does not help... It's still the same

Comment: Are you sure you have not duplicate username in your database ? because as it is write here: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_uniqueness_of , it can cause race condition troubles

Comment: Database is empty. When populated with few users, it still does not work.